# B2c - redirect link from User Flow to Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can I use an hypertext link in a user flow to access to a custom policy interface? So that if the user clicks on the link, he is redirected from user flow to custom policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t link to another policy using a hyperlink in another. It doesn’t matter if it’s user flow - custom policy or any combination. It will not work because the authentication library state will not match the expected state at the start of the auth request.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, yes. It really depends on what the flows are.

However, it is not recommended to mix the two e.g. if you sign-up a user with a built-in policy, you can not sign in for that user with a custom one.

Rather make everything custom.

**Update**

There is a list of custom policies [samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples).

You can find one here that matches your needs.

In the B2C portal, there is a menu where you configure how you want the custom policy to [run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#test-the-custom-policy) e.g. what application to use.

This creates a link. That's the link you can use for the hypertext.

**Update 2**

This is an interesting one.

I agree with @JasSuri but in terms of the question "Can I use a hypertext link in a user flow to access a custom policy interface" you could have the link in a built in flow for forgotten password pointing to the custom policy password flow. I tried it and you can reset the password no problem.

Since the actual use case was not defined. it's difficult to know exactly when and where the custom policy link is added.

But best practice is not to mix built-in and custom!

Comment: If is it possible, how can I do it please?

Comment: Why can't you have separate user flows for sign in and sign up.

Comment: And the sign up / sign in flow already has a link to create a new account.

Comment: indeed we use the link in sign in / sign up to create a new account, except that instead of going to another user flow we must redirect to a custom policy page.

Comment: Maybe you should document your use case in the question. Why do you have to redirect to a custom policy? Or why can't you just use custom policies for everything?