# B2C - where can we change the redirect link in a custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

where are the links declared in a custom policy? how to change please the redirect of the link?
I want to change the redirect of forgot your password link.

Comment: Change it to do what? And why?

Comment: to redirect to another  custom policy

Comment: You shouldn’t do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70215775/8357357. You can use JS to override a link, but it should point to myapp.com/forgotpassword.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use Javascript on the page element.

Comment: Is there another way to do this without using javascript?

Comment: No there is not.